# Markdown and Pages

Tags: pages, markdown

I am looking for the best combination for working on a structured document and sharing it in Markdown format.

My favorite editor is Pages, in full screen mode. There I can see how the finished document actually will look like. Unfortunately, there is no direct export to markdown.

I've seen another question on the topic focusing on Markdown editors (I've tried a few) but I'd like to know if there's a clean way to export from Pages to Markdown. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you mean to do, but is "sharing it on Markdown" any different than sending a plain text file elsewhere? I use pages all the time for editing plain text documents and use [Marked](http://markedapp.com/) to preview things if needed. With a little practice, working directly with the raw text becomes effortless.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are so loyal to Pages if you want to write Markdown documents? What could it do better than an editor intended for the Markdown syntax?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert from Rich text in pages to markdown syntax? If so, then there is not a method to do this, at least not to the best of my knowledge. Generally, markdown is used as a base to convert to another file type.

Comment: @bmike Sorry, I wrote it in an ambiguous way, I meant "export it in markdown format". I'll have to share the Markdown file, but this is part of the overall story, non necessarily part of the question.

Comment: @Gerry I can be not so loyal anymore if a find a better combination. Currently Pages provide me better individual productivity in the writing phase. [IAWriter](http://www.iawriter.com/) is the best option I've found so far for writing, but still missing something, compared to pages. Please consider, that I'd like to keep rich editing in pages, and eventually lose some of the styles in markdown. Well, that's my goal. If it isn't workable, I'll stick to some plain markdown editor.

Comment: By the way, @bmike, thanks for pointing me to Marked. I'll give it a look! :-)

Comment: I personally also like IAWriter the most, but starting from Pages and converting to Markdown is essentially against the spirit of Markdown (which is ment to create a "source" of your documents), because you will need to map a richer set of formatting options to the least common denominator in Markdown. The results will be a bit unpredictable at best. Markdown is very easy to learn, and for most if not all people should be the faster way to write and format documents.

Comment: @Gerry Can't say if that's against the spirit :-) but looks like that that's the mainstream way. I'll try to work the other way around: Markdown as a source and eventually turn the result into a richer format. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not usre about the "spirit of Markdown" stuff. I found iA Writer to be totally obstinate in its refusal to even allow sizing of text on screen (as if _everyone_ has the same size monitor). Like the OP, I use Pages for composition because it's got superb text display and fluiditiy. I go on to  paste into a .md document -- which in my case is a Ulysses sheet stored in its file system. As nice as Ulysses is, it still doesn't stack up to Pages in terms of quality of font rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a two-step process. There are a lot of scripts available to convert doc files to Markdown, so in Pages first export to Doc, then use one of those scripts.

Comment: I had success using pandoc on the command line to convert a word docx file (created with pages) to a markdown md file. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448176/how-to-convert-rtf-to-markdown-on-the-unix-osx-command-line-similar-to-pandoc/30472827 and https://publisha.github.io/conversion/markdown/2017/02/10/frompages2markdown-md/